# UV bake creating tearing lines pointing to vertices

Tags: materials, uv, baking

I'm getting these odd stretched lines when baking a glowy PBR material to a texture file. As you can see on the render preview, these lines do not exist on the model itself and do not correspond to verts/edges/faces that exist during the bake.

Things I've tried without success: changing UV projection options, adding/subtracting margin on the UVs, adding/removing seams, trying GPU & CPU computation, disabling AO/emit/etc, and changing scale of UV image.

I'm new to UVs and am very much out of ideas on my end.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any other modifiers on your object, if so make sure the render button is off(camera icon).

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have any modifiers, Zak. Issue seems to stem from curved areas pointing toward one of the corner vertices in every instance. I have tried to merge a significant number of verts on the curves to see if that would affect the issue but the lines remain (sorry, I can't comment now that I've created an account because I lack the required reputation to comment on my own post)

Comment: Can you link a file, with the bake settings that you're using?  Like get it ready to bake, then just save the file.

Answer (score 0):

Attaching link to archive including the Blend file and associated UV map. Let me know if there are any issues with the file upload.

Unfortunately, it seems I cannot edit the original post, since connecting to my Gmail account removed access to the guest account I created when I originally posted the question >.>

[Link to UV and Blend .rar file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aLOHLJFVDlIC5_Ys1M-YIh6_9EZmmH6Q/view?usp=sharing)